# How to access protected routes in postman?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm using spring boot and oauth2 to create a github single sign on, now i have protected routes that I want to test, but when I try to access them it tells me that I need to login.

What I have tried to is to create a GitHub personal access token, and in my postman in the integrations tab select github and add a new integration. But it didn't work. Still asks me to login.

How can I access the protected routes using the Github login?

This is how I added my github personal access token key and created the integration in postman.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `oauth2Login` (and defined the required client configuration for OAuth2 login to work), **your requests are secured with sessions** (not Bearer access tokens) => you have to send a valid session cookie with your requests for it to be authorized.

You might go through the OAuth2 login process using your browser as normal and use the Postman interceptor to capture the session cookies. Sample tutorial [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNDSEZF5IpA).

But, if you are using Postman, you are probably writing a REST API. As you are using OAuth2 for security, this Spring application(s) would probably better be configured as a stateless resource server (spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server instead of spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client, `oauth2ResourceServer` instead of `oauth2Login`, disabled sessions and CSRF protection). But this requires to setup a Backend For Frontend (BFF) in front of it to provide with `oauth2Login` and something to bridge between session based security and token based security (the Spring Cloud Gateway with `TokenRelay` filter in the case of [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)).

See [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for some OAuth2 background and the various configuration options.

Comment: Hi @ch4mp thank you for your answer, I didn't know about this BFF pattern, I'll search more about it and check your tutorials.

Comment: look for "OAuth2 BFF". Backend For Frontend has a very vague definition and is used for different purposes. The idea here is to have the frontend(s) authorizing requests to the backend (the BFF) with session + CSRF protection. An OAuth2 BFF replaces session cookie with the access token it keeps in the corresponding session before forwarding requests to resource servers (which don't keep sessions and are interested only in access tokens)

Comment: I'll look for it, thank you for your help.